# White image as Youtube video preview

Tags: youtube, render, preview

I am embedding Youtube videos in a web site but sometimes (it is not a deterministic error, sometimes everything works fine, sometimes not) instead of the youtube preview image, only a white square is rendered.
If I inspect the element, I can see that actually there is a tag IMG with the correct SRC attribute, and if I navigate this URL I get the correct image.

Is there any reason why I get the white square in the web site?

Thanks,
Stefano

Comment: Can you specify which browser and which version of it you use?

Comment: Now that you have said that, I realised that the problem occurs on Chrome 14.0.835.202 but not on Firefox 12.0